# To what does Yojimbo refer?

Tags: yojimbo

Nowhere in the subtitles is Yojimbo mentioned, except for the title of the movie.

The ronin says his name is "30-year old Mulberry field", and we are meant to know this is an alias, of the moment.

The Wikipedia page does not draw a reference to this name, until several sequels later.

**As a stand-alone film, how are we meant to infer the meaning of this name?**

Comment: Yojimbo means bouncer or bodyguard in Japanese. Is that all you were looking for or did you want something more in depth?

Comment: Excellent.  Someone should add that to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Perhaps it was meant only for the japanese speaking audience?

Comment: @Luciano Perhaps worldwide audiences could try to be more curious about other cultures and words from languages they do not know? Just typing "yojimbo meaning" in Google directly led me to this explanation: https://findwords.info/term/yojimbo

Comment: @wip I'm not saying you should not be curious, I'm saying perhaps the director didn't care about worldwide audiences. Same with a lot of North American movies with very specific jokes and references.

Comment: Yes, interesting point. Maybe in 1962 a renowned Japanese director making a movie about 1860 Edo Japan did not think about that aspect. Publishers could have thought about localizing the title, but apparently preferred to keep the original version.

Comment: It is unlikely that Kurosawa did not consider a Western audience; he was greatly influenced by John Ford.

Answer (score -1):

It's said in the movie.

"Samurai, want to be a bodyguard?"
later
"Do you want to buy me?","As a bodyguard".